# Operator overload or comparison function in C++ priority queue

Tags: c++, stl, performance

I am writing a program in C++ and I would like to define priority queue of one of my class. I need it to compare objects by one of the class member variable. I have used an operator< overload, but I know there is a second way to achieve this goal - special function defined with queue definition. Which way is better, more esthetic and more efficient? And how to write such a function?

I have done it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

class Human {

    public:
        string name;
        int age;
        Human(string name, int age);
};

Human::Human(string name, int age) : name(name), age(age) {}

bool operator<(Human a, Human b) {return a.age < b.age ? true : false;}

int main() {

    Human p1("Child",5);
    Human p2("Grandfather",70);
    Human p3("Older son",20);
    Human p4("Father",40);
    Human p5("Younger son",10); 

    priority_queue<Human> Q;

    Q.push(p1);
    Q.push(p2);
    Q.push(p3);
    Q.push(p4);
    Q.push(p5);

    while(!Q.empty()) {

        cout << "Name: " << Q.top().name << ", age: " << Q.top().age << endl;
        Q.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return a.age < b.age ? true : false;` is looking kinda awkward

Comment: maybe `return a.age < b.age;`?

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. I agree, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Style

If your type has an intrinsic, "natural" ordering, it is reasonable to express that with a built-in operator.

If the ordering varies by how you're using the type (eg. you have one collection of Human sorted by age, one by height, one by IQ), then it seems sensible to say the ordering is a property of the container instead of the type.

---

### Implementation

You can write a free function, or use a functor if you need state.

Note that these are both *exactly* as amenable to inlining as a built-in operator, so there is no inherent difference in speed (it's probably harder for the compiler to prove a function pointer is inline-able though, so functors are generally preferred).

```
struct OrderByAge
{
    bool operator() (Human const &a, Human const &b) { return a.age < b.age; }
};
typedef std::priority_queue<Human, std::vector<Human>, OrderByAge> age_queue;
```

Comment: How can I write this kind of function? Where should I declare it?

Answer (score 2):

The overloading of the operator is the best way because only performs a comparison instruction, nothing can be more performant, so your solution is optimal.

Comment: But the comparison operator could perform a million comparisons for all you know. There is no efficiency advantage in using the operator or the functor approach.

Comment: maybe for all YOU know. I know that a comparison is an atomic processor function. However I didn't say that overloading is better than any function but I said that overloading is no worse than any other function.

Comment: A comparison of two `std::strings` is atomic? OK, I learned something today.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct DatenWert {
    int ordnungsnummer;
};

class DaternWert_Compare {
public:
    bool operator()(DatenWert& t1, DatenWert& t2)
    {
       if (t1.ordnungsnummer < t2.ordnungsnummer) return true;
       return false;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    priority_queue<DatenWert, vector<DatenWert>, DaternWert_Compare> pq;

    DatenWert wert2 = {2};
    DatenWert wert1 = {1};
    DatenWert wert3 = {3};

    pq.push(wert1);
    pq.push(wert2);
    pq.push(wert3);

    while (! pq.empty()) {
       DatenWert t2 = pq.top();
       cout << setw(3) << t2.ordnungsnummer << " " << setw(3) << endl;
       pq.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

3
2
1